# Wordpress | Is it possible to insert markup after the post title's markup using a hook?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a plugin that needs to insert some links after the main title on any given page/post.

If I use the `post_title` filter, my markup is added *inside* the `H1` for example... not *after* it.

```
function so_title_filter( $title, $id = null ) {

    if (in_the_loop()) {
        $title = $title . "<p>Custom markup!</p>";
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'so_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Is there a way to add custom markup *after* the title's markup?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible using a hook. If you look at the source code for [`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/), you'll notice there are no filters on the `before` and `after` arguments, only on the function `get_the_title()`. There's also no consistent way themes implement titles, for example they could use something like `the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );` or `<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>`, so this isn't something you can expect to achieve with hooks.

You could do it with some JavaScript though

PHP (add a class to your injected element)

```
function so_title_filter( $title, $id = null ) {

    if (in_the_loop()) {
        $title = $title . '<p class="moveme">Custom markup!</p>';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'so_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

JS

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery( '.moveme' ).each( function() {
         jQuery( this ).insertAfter( jQuery( this ).parent() );
    });
});
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/cameronjonesweb/pen/NLaEex)